# Transfer Sparkle Updater private key signature EdDSA (ed25519) to new computer

Tags: xcode, keychain, ed25519, sparkle, key-rotation

I have an XCode 12.4 Swift project that I have been distributing since 2 years. I'm using the [Sparkle-Project](https://sparkle-project.org/) updating mechanism. macOS 10.15.7
I want to *slowly* migrate to a new Mac, XCode 13.4, macOS 12.6.5.

I'm having problems transferring my Sparkle private key signature EdDSA (ed25519).
I can't export the key from Keychain, the option is greyed out.
This user had similar issues:
[Sparkle Integration with security in mac app cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704281/sparkle-integration-with-security-in-mac-app-cocoa)

I think that using a new key signature with Sparkle's `generate_keys` tool will render my XCode project unusable until I have it up and running on the new machine.

**Is there a way to export or transfer the key?**

Sparkle documentation mentions [key rotation](https://sparkle-project.org/documentation/#rotating-signing-keys) but I don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

- On the old Mac open Keychain.app.
- Create a new custom keychain with ⌥⌘N.
- Copy the keys and items you need with ⌘C/⌘V to the new created keychain.
- Quit Keychain.app, goto ~/Library/Keychains (~ is your home folder) and copy the file with the name of the new keychain to the same location on the new computer.
- On the new computer open Keychain.app.
- If the custom keychain does not appear add it with ⇧⌘A.
- Copy the items to the Login keychain.
- Delete both custom keychains on both machines.

Answer (score 1):

With Sparkle 2 it is now possible to export/import the key with their   `generate_keys` tool in Terminal.

Export:

```
generate_keys -x my-private-key-file
```

Import:

```
generate_keys -f my-private-key-file
```